Used Transistor as Switch LED
I designed simple circuit using transistor as switch for my led. I used npn transistor. The input voltage is 46V. The current input is 15mA. My question is my circuit is correct or not?


Even assuming the LEDs are 6 V (I'm still thinking about how that may be), they stack up to 18 V. You are applying 46 V. That doesn't sound right to me. Usually, a current limiting resistor would be added in series with the LEDs so soak up the extra voltage. Even assuming you did that, as well, then R1 is a bit low. Perhaps 27 k, instead? Or 33 k? But you are missing the current limit resistor. So don't just change R1 and call it good. Also, perhaps you can explain why the LEDs are given as 6 V?

@periblepsis thanks for explanation. Yeah. I need to add Resistor before the LED for extra voltage. Sorry. can you explain which part I need to add current limit resistor? The led I used is 3030 type. The Voltage forward is 6V. Thanks again

Thanks. The datasheet helps in explaining. The voltage is between 5.8 and 6.6 V with a typical of 6.28 V. So anywhere from 17.4 V to 19.8 V, with an average of 18.84 V. The current is shown as 150 mA. Not 15 mA. So a resistor of (46-18.9)/150 mA = 180 Ohms might be appropriate. However, R1 will need to be 3 k, or so. Not saying 6 k won't work. It probably will. But it depends. Anyway, wasted dissipation (5 W?) is going to be horrible. You would be a LOT better off with a buck switcher somewhere in the system.

In short, no.
46V is a lot more than the ~18V required, so either the transistor drops the balance (and gets hot), or the LEDs cook off from excess current flow.  Or the supply browns out in the process, or, some combination of all three.
Some more detailed possibilities:

If the LEDs are indication type (typically limited to If = 20mA), even if the BJT is a low-hFE power transistor (say ~20, though it's most likely over 50 at this current), the 7.5mA base current is multiplied to over 150mA and the LEDs quickly expire.
If the LEDs are illumination type and adequately heatsinked, the BJT heats up, so hFE rises, and heats up some more, etc. This is referred to as "suicide bias".
If the BJT is a small-signal type, it's dissipating 10s of W and simply blows up.  The LEDs may be damaged in the process.
If the LEDs are in fact lamps (with internal limiting/protection or even conversion), it may be fine.

Typically a resistor is connected in series with LEDs, to limit current, and then any saturated switch can be used to turn them on/off.
A transistor can be used as a current source/sink, but a different circuit is required to address the "suicide bias" here.
Preferably, a switching power supply is used, to convert directly to the 18V required, without costing heat dissipation and poor efficiency.
Without datasheets for the LEDs and BJT, a more detailed analysis is not possible.

There is a datasheet on the LEDs. Luckily. And provided by me in comments quite a while ago.

@periblepsis I don't see where OP mentioned this.

The OP mentioned "3030" and the datasheet I provided shows the approximate voltage difference across them that the OP mentions. I think that's good enough. Not perfect. But close enough for horse shoes.

"3030" is, most likely, a footprint dimension; it could apply to anything.  Even among LEDs, there are many commonly available in such packages, and I would not assume identity based on four characters and a voltage.

Ah. So my mistake then? The datasheet I found does match the OP's voltage values, within reason.

What it is, is a reasonable guess; say if I made a worked example, I might use it or a similar datasheet. But it can't be considered exact, based on basically no evidence. I don't know offhand how much variation exists within LED product lines, or say if they ever have internal resistors, or how ratings might vary with color (6V could also be triple-chip red, I suppose); or anything specialized (onboard controller/flasher/etc.). And other readers likely don't know either, so would be unable to review and confirm such an answer: upvoting such an assertion would be unreasonable.

Yeah. I'll leave it there, then. Obviously, you feel there is still some unsettled issues. And I won't take issue with that. I admit I thought the datasheet I provided matched well enough. But I don't have a comprehensive view, either. So I'll stop at this point and leave things where they are. Enough said, already.

Yeah, I prefer to take a judicious, or engineered if you will, approach to answering questions. And, it's good, I think, to articulate this process from time to time, to discuss practice, or to show others how or why one makes decisions about something. This conversation might be teetering towards "meta", but I'd gladly give readers the chance to "peek behind the curtain" as it were. Cheers!

Enjoyed the discussion! I follow your perspective. :) Thanks for the time. Appreciated!
